# How to implement debounce inside of useEffect when dealing with Event Listeners?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener, debouncing

I see questions aplenty about useEffect and debounce but this use case is a little different. I was having some trouble with `fetchBookList` not having access to state variables in the same component and it turns out on mount that function only has access to "stale" state, hence this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const handleScroll = () => {
    if (Math.ceil(window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.documentElement.scrollHeight) {
      fetchBookList();
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, {
    passive: true
  });
  return () => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  }

}, [bookList, bookType])
```

Re-creating the `handleScroll` is not the optimal solution but it does work. The problem is, with this code when the user hits the bottom of the screen there's no throttling in place so instead of fetching just once, multiple calls go out as in an instant the viewport may or may not be at the very bottom of the screen.

In this particular case, how does one go about debouncing the `fetchBookList` call so it only fires once every second or so max?

Comment: Is that throttling the `fetchBookList()` ?

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused. Are you asking how to throttle the event listener callback function, or how to access non 'stale' states?

Comment: @Codenewbie `fetchBookList()` will run multiple times when the user reaches the bottom of the page. Because this function is inside of useEffect, it doesn't seem like debouncing it is simple as this particular wrapper will re-run multiple times thus negating the timeouts that debounce `fetchBookList` (best I understand it)

Comment: I this something similar to infinite scrolling behavior ? fetch more books when user is at the end of the page ... as I understand .... then you could search for the infinite scroll